# Explain чем in this sentence

Tags: грамматика

I came across this sentence:

> Я мало чем могу помочь, но могу поделиться с тобой старым хаком
>   статуса профиля.

I'm confused with мало чем. How is it used?

Comment: consider - Чем (with what) ты можешь помочь? - Ничем (with nothing)! or Мало чем (with little/not much)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Чем' is a form of 'что' meaning 'what'. This is exactly the question that is used when you learn cases ('чем' is instrumental case, number 5 = 'творительный').
[image]

Translate it word-by-word and it will be clear:

> Я **мало чем** могу помочь, но могу поделиться с тобой старым хаком
>   статуса [от] профиля

=> word-by-word =>

> I **little what** can help, but can share with you old hack status
>   [of] profile

=> shake it =>

> **Little what** I can help, but can share old profile status hack with you

=> add English grammar =>

> *There is* **little with what** I can help you, but *I* can share *an* old profile status hack with you

Answer (score 1):

This means:

> There is not many ways I can help.

Another valid sentence would be *Я мало что могу для тебя сделать* («There is not much I can do for you»).

*чем* and *что* in these examples are similar to *которыми* and *которые* here:

> Мало **действий, которыми** я могу помочь.
>   Мало **действий, которые** я могу для тебя сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Literally (**чем** ~ *what **with*** or ***by*** doing what):

> There are not many things I could help you **with**, however I'd share [help you **by** sharing]
>   an old hacked profile status (with you).

Answer (score 1):

This simply means "**not much**", as in "`There isn't much I can do for you`".
Alternatively you can put it as "`There's little I can do for you`".

It's one of those turns of speech that sound awfully awkward and artificial if you try to translate them closely, so I would not even try to try to interpret "**мало чем помочь**" directly.

If you really want to translate "**помочь**" directly as "**help**" rather than "**do**", you'd have to use it as a noun, not a verb. "`I'm a afraid I can't be much [of a] help...`"

The literate translation is "`[There's] little with which I can help you`", so you can see you can't really use it or shape it in any way that would sound idiomatic, or normal even, in English.

Answer (score 0):

**Мало чем** is the instrumental of the set expression **мало что** "not a lot [of things]". It belongs to a certain category of expressions.

Think of **кое-что**. The pronoun meaning "a certain something" or, alternately, "a few things here and there".

There's a limited number of adverbs that combine (without hyphenation) with **что** to form set expressions that are pronoun-like without technically being pronouns.

The major ones are **мало что**, **много что**, **(не)известно что**, **(не)понятно что**, and the postpositioned **что надо**. There are others, (even) more colloquial and not necessarily adverbial, such as **не пойми что** or **чёрт-те что**; one, **Бог знает что** has an exact English equivalent in *God knows what*.

Just like you also get **кое-кто**, **кое-где**, **кое-как**, etc., these pseudo-affixed adverbs can combine with any other interrogative/relative pronoun. E.g. **мало где** "not in a lot of places", **много как** "in many [possible] ways", etc.

It's a matter of pure convention that they're not hyphenated. For all intents and purposes, **мало** and **чем** in your example should be thought of as a whole.